# Top three documents by group using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

What I try to achieve is Top 3 documents by AccessGroup. By the Top 3 I mean documents that have a largest count. My current solution returns:

`DocumentId   AccessGroupId    Count
2            1                5 
1            1                3 
3            1                2 
5            1                2 
4            1                1 
6            1                1 
8            1                1 
10           1                1 
        ...  2  ...`

My goal is:

`DocumentId   AccessGroupId    Count
2            1                5 
1            1                3 
3            1                2 
        ...  2  ...`

I made a runnable LINQPad program:
[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ttamminen/f4fe95303845a90b4ccb3ceca8b75a1f)

```
void Main()
{

    var sampleData = new List<Foo>();
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 1, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 1, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 1, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 5, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 6, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 5, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 8, AccessGroupId = 1 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 10, AccessGroupId = 1 }); 

    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 2, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 3, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 2 });
    sampleData.Add(new Foo { DocumentId = 4, AccessGroupId = 2 });      

    var x = (from entry in sampleData
     group entry by new { entry.DocumentId, entry.AccessGroupId } into g
     orderby  g.Key.AccessGroupId, g.Count() descending
     select new { DocumentId = g.Key.DocumentId, AccessGroupId = g.Key.AccessGroupId, Count = g.Count() }
    );

    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

public class Foo {
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int AccessGroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want just the first 3 or the first three for each `AccessGroupId`?

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: Surely you are just missing a Take(3) from your current solution, you current solution gives all of them order, doing a Take(3) from each group will let you just have the top 3 from each group.

Comment: Can you clarify what the `... 2 ...` is suppose to mean in your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group by the `AccessGroupId` then from that grouping group by the `DocumentId` and order by the count and take the first 3.  Then you can use `SelectMany` to flatten out the top 3 documents for each access group.

```
var x = sampleData
    .GroupBy(x => x.AccessGroupId)
    .Select(accessGroup => new 
    { 
        AccessGroupId = accessGroup.Key, 
        TopThreeDocs = accessGroup.GroupBy(x => x.DocumentId)
                                  .OrderyByDescending(subg => subg.Count())
                                  .Take(3)
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x.TopThreeDocs.Select(y => new
    {
        x.AccessGroupId,
        DocumentId = y.Key,
        Count = y.Count()
    });
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

change your linq as below.

```
var x = (from entry in sampleData
                 group entry by new { entry.DocumentId, entry.AccessGroupId } into g
                 orderby g.Count() descending
                 select new { DocumentId = g.Key.DocumentId, AccessGroupId = g.Key.AccessGroupId, Count = g.Count() }
        ).Take(3);
```

Take(3) will select top 3 entries, hope it helps.

Comment: @Tx3 Please mark answered so it wont appear unanswered.

Comment: That's the top 3 by count for access group and document, not the top 3 by count documents for each access group, which is what I think the OP wants.

Comment: @SaketChoubey Mr juharr is right. Unfortunately, this query doesn't give the required end result.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It wont give the required end result, I misunderstood the question, However I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Using Linq

Would probably opt to do outside of linq if you're dealing with a particularly large dataset.

```
    sampleData
            .GroupBy(a=>new{a.AccessGroupId,a.DocumentId})
            .Select(a=>new{ Count=a.Count(),a.Key.AccessGroupId,a.Key.DocumentId })
            .OrderByDescending(a=>a.Count)
            .GroupBy(a=>a.AccessGroupId)
            .Select(a=>new{ AccessGroupId = a.Key, Values = a.Take(3)});
```

See the working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UXPs7N) if you want to check it out

## Using a dictionary

Pretty sure this is way more efficent, use a `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,int>>` to store the count.

```
    var cache = new Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,int>>();

    foreach(var item in sampleData)
    {
        if(!cache.ContainsKey(item.AccessGroupId))
        {
            cache[item.AccessGroupId] = new Dictionary<int,int>();
        }

        if(!cache[item.AccessGroupId].ContainsKey(item.DocumentId))
        {
            cache[item.AccessGroupId][item.DocumentId]=0;
        }

        cache[item.AccessGroupId][item.DocumentId]++;
    }


    var results = cache
                  .Select(a=>new{ 
                            AccessGroupId = a.Key, 
                            Values = a.Value.OrderByDescending(b=>b.Value)
                                    .Select(b=>new{ DocumentId = b.Key, Count = b.Value })
                                    .Take(3)
                  });
```

Less user friendly but pretty sure it is less expensive compared with using GroupBy unless you are using Linq-to-Something, here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aygdyM) if you want to check it

Answer (score 0):

I find this the easiest way:

You first need to get the count for each group, and then you need to order by that count and take the top 3 of each group and then flatten that list using Select Many:

```
var results = (from entry in sampleData
                group entry by new { entry.AccessGroupId, entry.DocumentId } into g
                select new
                {
                    AccessGroupId = g.Key.AccessGroupId,
                    DocumentId = g.Key.DocumentId,
                    Count = g.Count()
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .GroupBy(x => x.AccessGroupId)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Take(3));
```